# error in as.mcmc applied to jags() output in R?

Tags: r, r2jags

I've just switched from R2jags from R2OpenBUGS, and have noticed something I don't understand. After running the simulation using `jags()` and converting the output using `as.mcmc()`, the first sample always has very high deviance, and is typically very far from the converged parameter estimate. Running the same data with `bugs()` this sample does not appear. It's almost like the first sample is the *actual* first sample from the burn-in phase.

Reproducible code, including a bad initial estimate to show the bad parameter in the first sample of the `jags()` but not `bugs()` output.

```
require(R2jags); require(R2OpenBUGS); require(mcmcplots)

set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*x + rnorm(100)

jags.model <- function()
{
    # likelihood
    for( i in 1:n ){
        mu[i] <- alpha + beta * x[i]
        y[i] ~ dnorm( mu[i], tau )
    }

    # priors
    alpha ~ dnorm(0,0.001)
    beta ~ dnorm(1,0.001)

    tau ~ dgamma(1,1)
    sigma <- 1/sqrt(tau)
}

n <- length(x)

inits <- function() list( "alpha"=5,"beta"=5,"tau"=5 ) # very far initial estimate

dat <- list("x","y","n")

out.jags <- jags( dat, 
    inits=inits, model=jags.model, 
    n.iter=1000, n.thin=1, n.chains=2,
    DIC=TRUE,
    parameters.to.save=c("alpha","beta") )
codaout.jags <- as.mcmc(out.jags)

out.bugs <- bugs( dat, 
    inits=inits, model=jags.model, 
    n.iter=1000, n.thin=1, n.chains=2,
    DIC=TRUE,
    parameters.to.save=c("alpha","beta") )
codaout.bugs <- as.mcmc.bugs(out.bugs)


plot(codaout.jags)
x11(); plot(codaout.bugs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, the problem is that R2jags does not always handle the burn in period properly, as discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45193/r2jags-does-not-remove-the-burn-in-part-sometimes).